# Requisições simultâneas client side e server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Ao utilizar Ajax, eu crio uma requisição assíncrona para o meu servidor. Se eu utilizar N requisições ajax simultaneamente, eu ainda estou tratando estas requisições de forma síncrona no servidor?

Caso sim, para criar uma requisição assíncrona tanto no client-side quanto no server-side, eu precisaria utilizar programação com threads no servidor?

Quais são os métodos de se criar requisições assíncronas tanto front-end quanto back-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Se eu utilizar N requisições ajax simultaneamente, eu ainda estou tratando estas requisições de forma síncrona no servidor?

Depende da implementação do servidor. Normalmente, o método de resposta possui na declaração algo como `public async Task<>`, o que indica que a resposta será processada como uma thread em separado (ou seja, de forma escalável).

## Caso sim, para criar uma requisição assíncrona tanto no client-side quanto no server-side, eu precisaria utilizar programação com threads no servidor?

Exatamente.

## Quais são os métodos de se criar requisições assíncronas tanto front-end quanto backend?

Supondo que sua aplicação seja ASP.NET MVC, usando Web API 2 ou não, o protótipo do método fica mais ou menos assim:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Noticia>> GetNoticias()
{
    return await db.Noticias.ToListAsync<Noticia>();
}
```

- `async` indica que o método é executado de forma assíncrona;
- `Task` serve para indicar para o objeto que manipulará a sua thread qual o tipo de retorno que será feito;
- `await` [suspende a thread até que o retorno seja atribuído](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh156528.aspx). A suspensão da thread não interrompe outros fluxos que estejam sendo executados;

Comment: Como havia imaginado. Então em um método que não utiliza Async não é assincrono? Se eu realizar N requisições para um método não Async, este será tratado na thread main e irá ter seu retorno de forma síncrona, correto?

Comment: @Vinícius Exatamente.

Comment: @Vinícius Eu realmente gostaria de saber a sua necessidade. É para fins de estudos? É para fins de escalabilidade? Qual o propósito?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge, Existe uma página em um dos sistemas que utilizo que faz mais de 50 requisições Ajax para o servidor. Eu suspeitava que independente da quantidade de requisições, estava sendo executada de forma sincrona, como Cigano esclareceu. A aplicação é em webforms.

Comment: @Vinícius Executar de forma síncrona faz alguma diferença pra você? Pergunto isso porque 50 requisições assíncronas para o servidor não deve afetar a aplicabilidade. Quem sabe a performance, mas não a aplicabilidade – a sua linguagem e o servidor saberão o que fazer quando as requisições simultâneas forem feitas. Nota: simultaneidade é diferente de concorrência.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge, faz sim. São testes de pings, então acredito que podem ser feitos simultaneamente sem impactar na aplicabilidade.

Comment: @Vinícius Você quer executar os testes simultaneamente ou você faz coisas em paralelo à estes testes, como, por exemplo, registrar em um log?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge, apenas testar. O método que deve ser assíncrono apenas testa e retorna se este ip existe ou não. COmo são muitos ip's, o tempo da execução de todos é muito grande.

Comment: @Vinícius Entendi. Então, vá de threads! Vou deixar a minha resposta para fins de conhecimento.

Comment: ótimo @GuilhermeOderdenge, deixe-me tirar uma última dúvida. Caso eu faça N requisições ajax simultaneamente para um web-service, este irá tratar cada requisição como um 'cliente' ou será enfileirado? Levando em consideração que está com programação sem async.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine o seguinte cenário: 50 usuários estão acessando a sua aplicação simultaneamente. Eles fazem coisas lá, e algumas delas são requisições do cliente para o servidor – tais requisições são *assíncronas*.

Quando isso acontece, várias requisições paralelas e simultâneas são enviadas para o seu servidor e ele resolve como lidar com isso.

Ao disparar mais de uma requisição (assíncrona ou não) por vez para o servidor, o comportamento do mesmo não é baseado necessariamente em um método por você empregado.

Vamos analisar uma pergunta sua:

> [...] eu precisaria utilizar programação com threads no servidor?

Um processo assíncrono é disperso às threads – não são coisas que devem ser comparadas porque tem propósitos relativamente diferentes.

Então, para deixar bem claro: você não precisa fazer absolutamente **nada** no servidor se não achar necessário. As suas requisições são feitas para o servidor através de um [método/verbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) e dependendo do encaminhamento de um intermediário – controllers, por exemplo –, o seu aplicativo deve reagir de uma forma específica.

**Por que threads são diferentes de processos assíncronos?**

Threads dão a habilidade para um aplicativo de trabalhar com processos concorrentes. Um computador consegue navegar na internet e reproduzir música simultaneamente por causa delas: são processos paralelos que consomem processamento – processamento esse que é (re)aproveitado para executar múltiplas tarefas.

O seu aplicativo é uma coisa só: o que ele faz é de responsabilidade dele; se ele vai inserir alguma informação no banco de dados **E** exibir uma mensagem na tela: o problema é totalmente e exclusivamente dele – que, por sua vez, é um processo único.

A responsabilidade de disponibilizar o banco de dados para a inserção da informação e o navegador que é onde você vai exibir a mensagem é de responsabilidade do sistema operacional. Aqui, portanto, é onde entra as **threads**. A princípio, você **não** precisa e/ou vai gerenciar.

**Mas e se eu realmente quiser usar threads?**

**Você pode**. As linguagens oferecem meios e mecanismos pra isso – o C#, aliás, faz isso muito bem. O que estou querendo apontar é que você **não necessariamente precisa**.

Ambientes e linguagens web são equipados naturalmente para lidar com processos paralelos e você pode, na maioria das vezes, investir o seu tempo focando somente nas suas requisições; no seu "AJAX".