# Escalabiliade em sistemas .Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, cloud

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em VB.Net (Windows Forms), que utiliza banco de dados Mysql. Pretendo disponibilizá-lo na nuvem, qual seria a melhor forma para garantir escalabilidade na aplicação / banco de dados, utilizando-se de cloud computing? Mudar para Web based application, com Asp.net?

Se alguém tiver dicas ou materiais sobre esse paradigma, seria ótimo!!!

Comment: @Caputo Apesar de não parecer, esta pergunta pode ser respondida objetivamente.

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não tinha conhecimento sobre, e na dúvida também não sinalizei. Já exclui o outro comentário. []s

Answer (score 1):

## Qual seria a melhor forma para garantir escalabilidade na aplicação/ banco de dados, utilizando-se de cloud computing?

Utilizando arquitetura assíncrona em ASP.NET MVC. Basicamente, seus `Controllers` precisam ter o seguinte na declaração:

```
public async Task<Modelo> Index() {
    ...
}
```

[Nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27144/requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-simult%C3%A2neas-client-side-e-server-side/27152#27152) dou alguns detalhes de como as requisições funcionam.

O ambiente Azure já é configurado para usar um coordenador de transação distribuído e o Framework .NET mais recente (aceitando novas aplicações ASP.NET MVC até a versão 5, na data desta resposta, a mais recente).

Não vale a pena escrever um tutorial aqui [porque já existe este tutorial no site oficial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) (em inglês). Basta ler os conceitos, implementar os exemplos, e se houver dúvidas, estaremos respondendo suas perguntas aqui.